# how to use awk in bash -c do the ' ' in awk ' ' doesn't break the bash -c ' ' bash?

Tags: bash, awk, find, paste, xargs

At the begining i have this scipt that put the stdout in a file.txt :

```
find .. -type f -not \( -path '/dev/*' -or -path '/proc/*' -or -path '/sys/devices/*' \) -print0 |
  xargs -0 bash -c 'paste -d ";" <(md5sum "$@") <(sha1sum "$@") <(sha256sum "$@") <(du -lh "$@")' bash
```

but it returns the path 5 times with spaces which makes things hard to parse.

So I did this :

```
 find / -type f -not \( -path '/dev/*' -or -path '/proc/*' -or -path '/sys/devices/*' \) -print0 |
  xargs -0 bash -c `paste -d ";" <(md5sum "$@" | awk "{print $1}") <(sha1sum "$@" | awk "{print $1}") <(sha256sum "$@" | awk "{print $1;}") <(du -lh "$@"| awk "{print $1;}")` bash
```

But it's not working

How would you do ?

I just don't know how to get : md5;sha1;sha256;size;path;md5;sha1;sha256;size;path;md5;sha1;sha256;size;path;md5;sha1;sha256;size;path;md5;sha1;sha256;size;path;md5;sha1;sha256;size;path; etc ...

Basically, all on 1 line.

Comment: The `$1` awk constructs need to be escaped so that bash does not interpret them as positional parameters.

Comment: It might be hard to read, but it's not hard to parse. Just pipe the output of your original command to something like `awk -F; '{print $1, $3, $5, $7, $9}'` (adjust the actual column numbers as needed).

Comment: @chepner I don't think so. The filename can contain spaces (which are not escaped by my coreutils) and contain substrings that look like hashes themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second command, you used backtick "quotes" for `` xargs -0 bash -c `...` bash ``. Those behave like `$(...)` so the command string was executed before `find | xargs` even started.
And in that command string, bash replaced `$1` before `awk` even started.

Command strings with nested quotes are easier to write in multiple steps using one helper variable for each level of quoting, but since you are using bash, you can export a function instead, which makes things trivial.

#### Your command correctly wrapped

```
f() {
  paste -d ";" \
    <(md5sum "$@" | awk '{print $1}') \
    <(sha1sum "$@" | awk '{print $1}') \
    <(sha256sum "$@" | awk '{print $1}') \
    <(du -lh "$@" | awk '{print $1}')
}
export -f f
find / -type f -not \( -path '/dev/*' -or -path '/proc/*' -or -path '/sys/devices/*' \) -print0 |
xargs -0 bash -c 'f "$@"' bash
```

#### Slightly improved and adapted to your needs

As you wanted, we can print all fields for all files in a single line
by replacing (`tr`) each `\n` by an `;`. The paths are not quoted in any way. If they contain a `;` or linebreak, parsing the result could be difficult. If you need some form of quoting try `printf %q` or `sed [-z] 's/.../.../g'`.

```
f() {
  paste -d ";" \
    <(md5sum "$@" | cut -c 1-32) \
    <(sha1sum "$@" | cut -c 1-40) \
    <(sha256sum "$@" | cut -c 1-64) \
    <(du -lh "$@" | cut -f1) \
    <(printf '%s\n' "$@") |
  tr '\n' ';'
}
export -f f
find / \( -path /dev/ -o -path /proc/ -o -path /sys/devices/ \) -prune -o \
  -type f -exec bash -c 'f "$@"' bash +
```

Comment: or simply replace every instance of `cut ...` or `awk { … } ` with : `awk NF=1`

Comment: I have no idea of what "NF" means.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Great suggestion, thanks! I didn't know that you could assign `NF`, but at least I know [how to look things up](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-NF-variable-2).

Comment: @akmot : `NF` doesn't have an official acronym definition but most would say "number of fields" (i.e. # of columns), so `NF = x` means keep all fields/columns from 1 to x, `NF = 1` means keeping only 1st column, and `NF = 0` means wipe the entire row clean. setting NF to floating point value will have it rounded *mostly* down to nearest integer (i think if you set like 3.999999…… for a very long chain of 9s it *might* round up to 4), while setting `NF` to anything less than 0 is a fatal error

Comment: @akmot : while `NF` is being set automatically by `awk` when each row is read in and parsed for your convenience, there's absolutely nothing sacred about `NF` - other than not setting it negative values, feel free to manipulate `NF` to your advantage, despite a widely held belief that `NF` is somehow a third rail that shouldn't be touched with a 10 ft pole

Comment: @Socowi what happens when you set `NF` is undefined behavior per [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) (POSIX says you can increase the number of fields to, say, 7 by setting `$7=""` but says nothing about what happens when you increase or decrease the value of `NF`) so YMMV with what `NF=1` does. Some awk variants might remove fields 2 and beyond while others might just ignore it and others could do anything else. I wouldn't rely on it as a replacement for the clearer, portable `print $1`.

Comment: While GNU awk will add/remove fields when you set NF, try `echo 'a b' | gawk --lint '{NF=1} 1'` and it'll warn you about that issue with the output `gawk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) warning: decrementing NF is not portable to many awk versions`. Most (all?) modern awks will add fields when you increase NF, despite that also being undefined behavior, so apparently the gawk providers decided not to issue a lint warning for that but since given <=7 fields of input, `$7=$7` will portably, as defined by POSIX, do the same as `NF=7` would do there's no point setting NF to a higher value.

Comment: There are various portable ways to strip fields off the end of a record (`print $1`, `$0=$1`, `sub(/([[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]*){3)$/,"")`, `match($0,/.../) && $0=substr(...)`, etc.), so don't assign a value to `NF` to reduce the number of fields unless you also state which awk variant(s) you intend your code to run on and their documentation states they support it. and if you want to add fields up to some number such as `7` then set `$7=$7` (to retain the value of `$7` if it already exists or create it as null otherwise) instead of setting `NF=7`.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you for the hint. I reverted *RAREKpopManifesto*'s suggestion. ¶ Your explanations are very detailed. You could turn that into a self-answered question and link that in the future :)